# How do I store an array of a custom structure in a file?

Tags: c#

I have a simple structure, as follows.

```
public struct Structure
{
    public byte Style;
    public string Value1;
    public string Value2;
    public int Value3;
    public bool Active;
}
```

I'd like to store an array of this structure using variable size as a file.  This file will be automatically loaded upon launch of the program, and updated as the program is in use.  I can figure out how to use it within the program, I'm just unsure on the method I should be using to store it.  I'm guessing I should use a binarywriter with prefixed byte lengths for each value?  If that's correct, an example of how to store and load a Structure[X] array would be incredibly helpful.  For aesthetic reasons, I would like to keep it in a file with a custom extension(ie: Array.ext), though I am not opposed to any other solution that will keep the data stored in that format between launches.

Comment: Why not to use some file based database, like SQLite, for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options. If you need the file to be stored in human readable format you can use an XML or JSON Serializer/Deserializer. Here is an XML example

```
public static void Serialize(Structure[] input) 
{
  var serializer = new XmlSerializer(input.GetType());
  var sw= new StreamWriter(@"C:\array.ext");
  serializer.Serialize(sw, input);
  sw.Close();
}    

public static Structure[] Deserialize() 
{
  var stream = new StreamReader(@"C:\array.ext");
  var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Structure[]));
  object obj = ser.Deserialize(stream);
  stream.Close();
  return (Structure[])obj;
}
```

If you want to use a binary serializer

```
public static void Serialize(Structure[] input) 
{
    var stream = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Array.ext");
    var bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();    
    bformatter.Serialize(stream, input);
    stream.Close();
}

public static Structure[] Deserialize() 
{
    var stream = new StreamReader(@"C:\array.ext");
    var bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    var obj = bformatter.Deserialize(stream);
    stream.Close();
    return (Structure[])object;
}
```

You need to mark your class as `[Serializable]` as well

```
[Serializable]
public class Structure { //etc
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks very much!  Sorry if this was too basic a question for here, been looking around google for an hour and thought I'd need to write a long function to store it as byte data and then reverse it.

Comment: I've updated it with a binary serializer (non-human-readable)

Answer (score 2):

You can add `[Serializable]` to this and use binary serialization to serialize your data to byte array. Than you can save it to file.

```
public static string Serialize(object o)
{
    using (var s = new FileStream())
    {
        _binaryFormatter.Serialize(s, o);
    }
}
```